# How to formally assign truth values to a proposition?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

What is the correct way of formally assigning a truth value to a proposition?

If $P$ is for instance true, can I just write $P = \mathbf{true}$? (Or **1** or **T** instead of $\textbf{true}$)

Should I use another sign than "$=$"?

What's the correct notation, what's the relation between a statement and its truth value?

Comment: See [Valuation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valuation_(logic))

Answer (score 2):

Main answer: There is no really standard notation.

At an elementary level, in my intro logic book I think I use ":=" for the assignment of a value to a wff (assuming some given valuation of relevant semantic primitives), and subscript "$:=_v$" when we need explicitly to relativize to some such valuation.

Note you are mentioning the wff and assigning a truth value to it. So, if you are being really pernickety you'd write

> '$P$' takes the value T

or

> '$P$' := T

for short. But that gets tedious to I'd just write

> $P$  := T

with the convention that ':=' comes with hidden quotation marks on the left.

Another convention would simply be to write the likes of $v({P})$ = T.

Subsidiary comment. You move from talking of a "proposition" via (apparently) talk of a wff to talk of a "statement". That's rather careless, given that these are used in different ways by different logicians. Talking as you do in the question about "formal assignments", however, suggests that you mean to be talking about assignments to wffs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What is a wff? What is the difference between it and statement and proposition? I used them synonymously (statement and proposition). Is $v(P)$ a function? Could I then write for example $(v(P \land Q) = T) \leftrightarrow (v(P) = v(Q) = T)$, to express that $P \land Q$ is true if and only if $P$ and $Q$ are both true?

Comment: Wff = well formed formula. Proposition (in some uses) is what is expressed by a meaningful sentence or wff (in context).

Comment: My impression is that virtually nothing in logic has a universally accepted name or notation.

Answer (score 2):

A proposition is not literally the same thing as its truth value. This distinction is crucial when, for example, discussing the status of the *same* proposition in *different* contexts. Basically, in addition to the purely **syntactic** apparatus of the logical grammar itself there is also some **semantic** apparatus (e.g. *structures* in the case of first-order logic), and each "semantic object" will give rise to a function from propositions to truth values. So if you want to be very precise, you need to introduce some new notation: for example, maybe you introduce the notation $$\mathsf{tv}_\mathcal{M}(\varphi)=\mathsf{true}$$ to mean "the **t**ruth **v**alue of the sentence $\varphi$ in the context $\mathcal{M}$ is true."

Unfortunately there is not a standard notation here, and abuse of notation is actually quite common (e.g. "$\varphi=\mathsf{true}$"). Ultimately you should just follow whatever convention is used by your text, or **clearly** introduce a convention of your own.